# Websites such as jitsi can't access my camera when I use the TorBrowser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I would like to do a video chat but the TorBrowser doesn't allow websites to ask for access to my camera. Is that because webrtc is disabled? what's the setting to enable to allow it?

Comment: WebRTC is disabled in Tor Browser, and from what I remember you can't enable it safely because its peer-to-peer connection mechanisms aren't really compatible with Tor and would leak the user's IP address.

Comment: yeah but is that the reason why the camera can't be enabled?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I didn't want to write it as an answer. Hopefully someone else can help answer that.